# Vectorising a code using xor in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have an `mxn` array `r` in Matlab with elements that are zeros or ones.

I want to construct a vector `p` of dimension `mxn` such that for `i=1,...,m`

`p(i,1)=r(i,1)`

`p(i,2)=r(i,2)XOR r(i,1)`

`p(i,3)=r(i,3) XOR r(i,2)`

`...`

`p(i,n)=r(i,n) XOR r(i,n-1)`

This code does what I want but it is slow for `m,n` large. Could you suggest something faster?

```
m=4;
n=5;
r=[1 1 1 1 1; ...
   0 0 1 0 0; ...
   1 0 1 0 1; ...
   0 1 0 0 0];

p=zeros(m,n);

for i=1:m
    p(i,1)=r(i,1);
    for j=2:n
        p(i,j)=xor(r(i,j),r(i,j-1));
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure:

```
p            = zeros(m,n);
p(:,1)       = r(:,1);
p(:,2:end)   = xor(  r(:,1:(end-1)),   r(:,2:n)   );
```

What we're doing here is:

1. Pre-allocating the array. Same as your code.
2. Fill in the first column of `p` with the first column of `r`
3. Fill in the 2nd - last columns of `p` with the desired `XOR` operation. As inputs to the `XOR` we are using two large sections of `r`. The first is the 1st - (last-1)th columns. The second is the 2nd through last columns.